# Printing from a list of lists

Tags: python

What is the best way to print elements from a list of lists? I have a list that looks like this:

```
l1 = [['hello', 'world', 'bye'], ['name', 'tour', 'now']]
```

I would like to print from this, element by element, so something like:

```
hello name
world tour
bye now
```

I was thinking of using a while loop, something like:

```
while i < 3:
    print(l1[0][i], l1[1][i])
    i -= 1
```

But instead of providing the [0] and [1], I would personally prefer it to be coded for a general case.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(l1[0])):
    for j in range(len(l1)):
        print(l1[j][i], end='')
        if j != len(l1)-1:
            print(' ', end='')
    print()
```

Comment: Thank you, but sadly the issue with this method is that it leaves a blank space at the end of the line that it prints

Comment: So basically you are checking to see if it's NOT the last element, and if that's true we add the space, otherwise no space is added. Right?

Comment: Exactly. There are more elegant solutions but this is anyway scalable :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the simplest way would be

```
for l in zip(*l1):
    print ' '.join(l)
```

Comment: oops, there was already another answer using `zip(*l1)`. sorry about that. This answer wouldn't require two joins though.

Answer (score 1):

use zip to merge the two lists together element by element: `print([' '.join(line) for line in zip(*l1)])`

EDIT: to get the same output as specify by the OP:

`print('\n'.join(' '.join(line) for line in zip(*l1)))`